# Extension method on class - good or bad idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, extension-methods

I already have Entity Framework in place along with a repository and some static classes/methods for manipulating the data. Here's a typical example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Supplier> Contains(IEnumerable<int> idList)
{
    return SupplierView.Select().Where(x => idList.Contains(x.ID));
}
```

These methods query my EF repository and sometimes I need to pass a number of variables to get the data I need back.

Given that my Supplier entity already exists, I'm contemplating making my queries extension methods using the class, something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Supplier> GetSimilar(this Supplier s)
    {
        return SupplierView.Select().Where(/* the criteria matches */));
    }
```

It would only be used for querying data - but as I'm basing the extension method on the entire entity, I'm not sure whether this is a great design idea - but it's certainly more convenient that passing params/validating them etc.

I already have a partial class set up for my main entities, but I tend to add properties, low impact stuff.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there are any obvious reasons to pick either of approaches - you need to look at your overall code and see where such methods fit best. Maybe you have many varying queries and they naturally grouped together or maybe you want intelisence benefits but dislike huge kitchen sink classes... I feel there is no real "this is the way" answer...

Comment: Thanks for your comments Alexie. I have relatively little experience in this environment - I don't dislike using a class in this way, but the purists my say it breaks the rules of encapsulation etc.

Answer (score 12):

Is `Supplier` a class of your own?

If yes, then I'd recommend just *extending* that class - instead of tacking on extension methods.

If it's a class generated from the database by EF, it's a `public partial class` so you can easily write additional methods for `Supplier` in a second file, also using the `public partial class` - those are then merged into **one single .NET class** at compile time.

I like extension methods and they make a lot of sense - if you need to add methods to classes that **you don't control** - e.g. .NET framework classes, or third-party classes.

Comment: Extensions methods also make sense when you control your class but can't use a partial definition (typically when you try to extend your own class in another assembly). So depending on the OP's solution architecture partial classes might not be an option.

Comment: To clarify, EF is DAL - above are in BLL. I already use partial classes to tack on my own Supplier properties, but the example I've given needs to query the database for other suppliers.

Comment: Sorry missed edit deadline: To clarify, EF is DAL - methods in example are in BLL. I already use partial classes to tack on my own Supplier properties (Entities project), but the example I've given needs to query the database for other suppliers so it would need to site above the DAL which Entities does not.